# loop over all rows in a dataframe and generate new column based on comparing other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| ID | name | value | mean | std | upper | lower |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 894.68 | 154.00 | 2.33 | 203.16 | 189.18 |
|  |  | 1045.28 | 196.17 | 4.50 | 204.00 | 186 |

For each row, I'm trying to create a new column by comparing the `value` with `upper` and `lower` as follow:

```
df['new_col'] = df[df['mean'].notnull()].apply(lambda x: False if x['value']>x['upper'] or x['value']<x['lower'] else True)
```

It gives me an error which is not ver clear to me: `KeyError: 'value'`. I guess it can't find `x['value']`, right? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your condition directly that will give you the boolean Series directly:

```
df['new_col'] = (~((df['value']>df['upper']) | (df['value']<df['lower'])) & df['mean'].notnull())
```

OR

via `apply()` but it will be slow because it is loop under the hood so pass `axis=1`:

```
df['new_col'] = df[df['mean'].notnull()].apply(lambda x: False if x['value']>x['upper'] or x['value']<x['lower'] else True,axis=1)
```

output of `df`:

```
     ID     name    value   mean    std     upper   lower   new_col
0   NaN     NaN     894.68  154.00  2.33    203.16  189.18  False
1   NaN     NaN     1045.28 196.17  4.50    204.00  186.00  False
```

Comment: I need to get Flase if all the conditions are met! I put `not` at the start but it doesn't work: `not (((df['value']>df['upper']) | (df['value']<df['lower'])) & df['mean'].notnull())`

Comment: @Birish updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**